# Center Text in a TextView with width and height in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this composable :

```
@Composable
fun MyApp() {

    var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isSelected) Color.Red else Color.Transparent)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello",
            modifier = Modifier.background(color = backgroundColor)
                .clickable(onClick = { isSelected = !isSelected })
                .width(100.dp)
                .height(40.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,

        )
    }
}
```

I expect `TextAlign.Center` centerlize Text of TextView, but it will be just centerlize horizontally. How can I make it center vertically as well?

Comment: No @Philip Dukhov
, when I add `.align(Alignment.Center)` it shows me an error in Android studio.

Comment: To use `.align(Alignment.Center)` you need to use `Box` instead of `Column`, why would you use it in the first place if you only have one item?

Comment: I used Box as well but this : `.align(Alignment.Center)` will not center my Text in the TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextAlign.Center` can only center your content horizontally.

To center it vertically you need to place it inside a container, like `Box`, and apply content alignment and your size modifiers to this container:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(100.dp)
            .height(40.dp)
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
            .clickable(onClick = { isSelected = !isSelected })
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

Also I'd say that generally this is a bad practice, because when user increase text size in the phone accessibility settings, your `Text` may no longer fit your box. Consider using `padding` instead.